# Why is negative lookahead is included in result?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

The expression Im using:

```
(?!.+\]\:)(.+)/g
```

The string:

```
some text I dont wan't ]: some text I want
```

The result:

```
]: some text I want
```

I was under the impression that the lookahead *excludes* from the following matching result. So why is `]:` being included in the result? Perhaps it's the `+` in the lookahead but I do not know what to replace it with.

Comment: Please specify programming language you're using in tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following simpler regex gives you correct result:

```
(?<=]: )(.+)
```

Output:

```
some text I want
```

There is no need to include wild characters when some specific ones are available (`]:` in this case).

Escape characters are not needed here but can be used - result stays the same.

Answer (score 5):

It is because you're using a lookahead that asserts that we don't have 1+ of any characters followed by `]` and `:` ahead. It starts matching right before `]:` because **lookahead condition satisfies** from that position (1+ character of anything).

What you probably meant was a lookbehind like this:

```
(?<=\]: ).+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/P4FWaV/1)

Comment: This is very similar to my answer. Good to get confirmation from a real expert.

Answer (score 0):

I believe negative lookahead is an `assertion` so it doesn't actually consume any character it matches. I think your (.+) is what is matching it.

You may use:

```
(?!.+\]\:)\s+(.+)
```

Then you can use Group 1

[Example Online](https://regex101.com/r/WEQuGB/1)